# Parallelogram Question

Tags: geometry

Find the area of a parallelogram with sides of length 6 and 8, and with an interior angle with measure $45^\circ$.

Can someone please have a solution without trig? I would like an answer with a $\sqrt{}$ (square root) if the answer permits.

Comment: does knowing the properties of a 45-45-90 triangle count as trig?

Comment: If you know that the diagonal of a square has length 6 can you find the length of the side of the square. If you can do that you should be able to draw a picture which will help you solve the problem. Do you know how to cut off one end of a parallelogram and glue it to the other end to make it a rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

[image: Really big hint]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Use the pythagorean theorem.  How *tall* is the parallelogram?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
By repositioning the triangle indicated, clearly area of parallelogram $=  8a$.

$ a^2+a^2 = 6^2 \\
\implies a^2 = 18 \\
\implies a=3\sqrt 2$

$\therefore $  Area $ = 24\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 0):

Drop a vertical line from one of the vertices and make a 45-45-90 right triangle. Remember that in a 45-45-90 triangle, if the legs have length x, then the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{2}x$, so if the hypotenuse in this case has length 6, the vertical has length $\frac{6}{\sqrt{2}}$. This is the height of the parallelogram. Multiply this by 8, the length of the other side, and you get $\frac{48}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $24\sqrt{2}$